# Web app for tracking arbitrary personal statistics?

Tags: web-apps, charts, information-management

I swear I've seen a web app like this, but can’t remember its name:

I'd love to be able to log certain aspects of my life, such as glasses of water consumed in a day, number of dirty dishes at the end of the day, or whatever else, and then have the data presented and charted for me nicely (i.e. something a bit better than spreadsheets).

Bonus points for being able to handle more than just a bunch of numbers every day, such as allowing me to keep a list of bands I've seen live, number of times seen each, etc.

I know all this sounds absurdly broad, but seriously, I did see a web service along these lines a year or two ago.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, this is one of my suggestion. I hope it was the suitable one for you.

**[Exist](https://exist.io)**, a way to visualise and understand all the data you create about your life. This application tracks your activities in one place. They collect all your activities data what's been happening at a glance. Besides that, you can overview your activity, suggest the happy days based on the mod's pattern, and the weekly summaries.

Comment: Did you use this WebApp? What are your experiences with it?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I never used Exist app before. So, I didn't have any experiences about that. I think the best way of it is you try the application. It was ready for 14-days, https://exist.io/signup/

Answer (score 1):

*Moderator's note (2023 December): It was reported that this software was no longer provided at the supplied link (link now removed), and that their may be NSFW content on the old site.  If someone has an updated link, please edit this answer or post a comment.  Thanks!*

There is Saga.

This will record where you go and what you do there.  It builds up a statistical picture over time of your habits and will keep track of events attended.

It can link to a wide variety of other apps, social sites, calendars etc. pulling all the information into one place.

Comment: Did you use this WebApp? What are your experiences with it?

Answer (score 0):

I make my own loggers using [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/).  Each time I submit something, it is saved to a spreadsheet with a timestamp, and I can customize what data I log each time.  I use it for weight log, symptoms log, cat weight log, etc. and can generate charts inside the Google Sheet it produces.

I don't have to worry about proprietary data formats or the app going out of business, and can always export my data to a regular spreadsheet if google goes out of business. :D

It doesn't log GPS location or work offline, however.